# How properly add a custom event in a PHPBB 3.1 style?

Tags: phpbb3

First time working "deep" with phpbb.

I'm adapting OneAll phpbb plugin for Comboot theme, and I have a particular issue about it.

For clarity, [here](https://github.com/chronomania/comboot) is the (fork of) theme i'm working, and [here](https://github.com/chronomania/comboot_oneall) is the repository of the adaptation. Different for prosilver, it have more places where login can be made directly (in navbar, or in the home page). Due to this, i needed to make some extra events to call the social icons from oneall to the theme, but they arent been called.

What are missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here the links of the specific lines in comboot where i add the custom events:
https://github.com/chronomania/comboot/blob/master/template/login_panel.html#L38
https://github.com/chronomania/comboot/blob/master/template/navbar_header.html#L88

Comment: AFAIK as long as you reference your template event correctly in whatever extension you use it should work fine. (in your extensions extension-name/styles/style-name/template/event directory)

Comment: i put exacly the same name of event-name.html in that directory, and still wont work. No html code from the extension are added.
The oneall also offers by default an "all" folder in styles folder. Maybe i need to add the event file in "all" too?

Comment: The 'all' directory is used either as a fallback for when there isn't a style specific directory, or if the extension looks the same in most styles (usually all prosilver based).

Answer (score 0):

Nailed my problem.

After inserting the text "IT WORKS" in the first line of both custom events html files, they're showed correctly in the right place. So both custom events works like intended.

Maybe i accidentally something very bad with the oneall code (maybe stripped too much) it doesn't show.

So, case closed. Thanks all for the help!